# iOS 7 Keyboard theme switching

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

Is there a way to build an app to switch between the light and dark keyboards in iOS 7 on the fly, in-app?

Example:  I'd like to make a writing app that can switch between 'Dark' and 'Light' themes. The keyboard should be the default white/light grey appearance for the Light theme, and the black/dark grey scheme for the Dark theme.  The two different themes can be simply toggled via an in-app option.

Possible?

(Please forgive me if this is a stupid/super-obvious question.  I'm not a programmer, but I want to hire one to build my ideas for iOS apps.  I just want to be sure I'm making requests that are actually possible, and could not find an answer to my specific question via the search here or google. Thanks!)

Comment: Appreciated.  I assume this is something that any iOS app programmer worth their salt, so to speak, can easily do?

Comment: Oh yeah. If you're hiring a programmer who can't do that, hire a different programmer.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for the short, direct answer.  Hopefully this may help someone else in the future; I was surprised that I couldn't find this sort of question or answer with just good ol' googling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use this:

```
[textField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark]; //Alert/Default/Dark/Light
[textField reloadInputViews];
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but will this allow the keyboard color to be changed back and forth within the app?  I realize that the keyboard can be set using the UIKeyboardAppearanceDark, but I don't know what reloadInputViews does; it doesn't sound like this answer addresses whether or not I can switch between the different keyboards in-app.

Comment: Yes, this will allow the keyboard color to be changed. For example, changing it to `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark` makes the keyboard black. `reloadInputViews` basically forces the update (so if the user has the keyboard up and you change the appearance, it'll update instantly). Does answer the question?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Thank you for the explanation and patience.  I appreciate you providing extra information, even if it is over my head as a non-programming-literate person.  Thanks, rebello!  =)

Comment: Haha great, no problem. Please accept my answer if you can (click the checkmark), I'd appreciate it.